# How to Recover Songs From an Ipod in ubuntu?

Tags: windows, 13.10, data-recovery, ipod, itunes

I replaced windows with ubuntu 13.10 and my data is gone.Now my only hope is my ipod.But i dont know how to recover songs from an ipod.Please give me some guidance for recovering my songs from ipod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging in the iPod as a USB device, copy all folders/files to the hard drive. Scan this folder/Add to Library using a media manager - Rhythmbox for example. All artist/album info will be read correctly. I think you can Sync it back to your iPod